# Create an array without the newlines, RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
"---\n- ''\n- Push Button\n- Power\n"
```

I need to convert the above to:

```
["Push Button", "Power"]
```

I have tried `.scan(/\w+/)` but unfortunately this gives me `["Push", "Button", "Power"]`

Thanks!!!

Comment: Why not just convert from the YAML instead of screwing around with strings yourself?

Comment: Didn't even know I was looking at YAML syntax. WOOHOO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load the YAML code,

```
YAML.load("---\n- ''\n- Push Button\n- Power\n")
```

Comment: If you want to reject empty strings (as your question suggests) you may want to add `.reject(&:empty?)` on the end.